# How to get a variable to persist

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can have this variable persist outside of the function so I could use it later on in my page or another page? Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sample form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="#">
           <label>Enter something</label>
           <input type="text" name="message" />
           <input type="submit" value="Submit me!" />
        </form>

        <!--Put this in the body of the html page-->
        <script src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
        <script src="init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

init.js

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        message = $('input[name=message]').val();
        alert('You put :' + message + '!');
        return false; //prevents default behavior submit
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked into `localStorage`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use `message` somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use message somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is all it takes.

```
var message;
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        message = $('input[name=message]').val();
        alert('You put :' + message + '!');
        return false; //prevents default behavior submit
    });
});
```